# Get the default tooltip for a file or folder in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file, tooltip

In Windows/C#, how do you get the default tooltip text as a string for a file or folder (meaning, the same text you would see when you hover over a file or folder in Windows)? Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

I've tried looking online but I could not find anything on this subject.

Comment: You may want to look at [little closer](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+fiel+explorer+tooltips&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)  - Also: See [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/02/10/customize-windows-explorer-tooltips/) Hint: It is all in the Registry..

Comment: @TaW So, parse all HKCR registry keys and build out the string using custom property on the target file or folder? You'd think there would be a built-in way to get the result of all of this.

Comment: @Alexandru I don't think that I am grasping what you want. Do you want to get the file data, or just the way the data is displayed on the tooltip?

Comment: @IanH. I want the tooltip text string. So, in the image above, you see the tooltip. What I want is the corresponding text it displays, in this case it would be `Type: TXT File\nSize: 0 bytes\nDate modified: 9/8/2016 11:22 AM`. This can be very different depending on whats in the registry, as @TaW points out.

Comment: @Alexandru Still, does it have to be the exact string that the system would provide? Getting the raw data would be alot easier and you could continue to use these values.

Comment: @IanH. Yes, the exact string.

Comment: @TaW: Unless officially documented, the registry is not a public programming interface. And I'm pretty sure there are shell functions to retrieve the tool tip text reliably.

Comment: @IInspectable I sure hope so.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after some in-depth research and some messing around I came up with this:

What values are displayed in a tooltip is decided by a registry key. More specifically, by the key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` with value `InfoTip`.
To get the value of this key, use some windows registry getting.

```
string root = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT";
string subkey = "*";
string keyName = root + "\\" + subkey;

string value = Registry.GetValue(keyName, "InfoTip", string.Empty);
```

`value` should then have the value of the registry key value.

After you have that, just divide the string into its parts. For me the string is `prop:System.ItemTypeText;System.Size;System.DateModified` so I would try to divide it into

```
System.ItemTypeText
System.Size
System.DateModified
```

by using some string splitting.

After that, use the `FileInfo` class to get the information of the inspected file, and format it in the way you got your registry key value.

Comment: This isn't going to work because the extent to which the registry extends itself to supply this functionality is quite large. For example, `HKCR\Directory` has `InfoTip` with `prop:System.Comment;System.DateCreated`. Not to mention, each file extension (`.docx`, `.doc`) could have its own HKCR entry with `InfoTip`. Some `InfoTip` entries even have links to internal resources contained within the files themselves. It would be a nightmare to write or to get working correctly.

Comment: @Alexandru Yeah, it would work, but probably only to a certain extent ... if you look at the other entries for the tooltips you could probably create cases for all of them, but it would be **alot** of work.

Comment: Maybe if you have a good year ahead of you and your requirement enabled you to write a kernel driver to do all of this...but, this isn't the case for me.